# How to set node_modules in a parent folder of project to angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, directory, node-modules

I'd like use a Angular framework like a template and use to make a lot contents, but for this, a need use a node_modules in a parent, else every content which create, I have to install node_modules. Is there a way to do this? Because if I use the command ng server, the angular cli return that depending on "angular/core"

Comment: Does your package.json file have the @angular/core ?

Comment: Yes!! I don't know if you understand, but my really problem is the node_modules is in outer of project.

Comment: Same issue here. There should be an option in the angular-cli.json file to specify the node_modules path.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3864